# Matching elements using XPath on Coded UI Tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

This is a noobish question but I am getting started with MS Coded UI Tests. And I was wondering if there's a way to find page elements using XPath, instead of the default matching mechanism? What I want to do, is match a parent elements and programmatically navigate down the DOM tree to get the elements I want to work with. This can be easily done with Selenium, but I am not sure how to do it with Coded UI Tests.

Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2011/12/28/sample-xpath-utility-for-coded-ui-test.aspx there is no built-in support, although a custom tool on top of CodedUI can do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to manage navigating an `xpath` using the `UITestControlCollection`. Use CodedUI's recorder to get to the top level control, then use `GetChildren` to navigate your way.  Keep in mind that the `xpath` changes because all the object types are similar, CodedUI's API doesn't distinguish.

Example:

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.UIYourWindowName.UIYourDocumentName; // mapped control
doc.Find();
UITestControl toline = new UITestControl(doc);
toline.SearchProperties["Id"] = "to_d"; // use the id of the top most control
UITestControlCollection toline1 = toline.GetChildren(); // get the child objects

toline1 = toline1[0].GetChildren(); // xpath: \\ctrl[@id='to_d']\item[0]
toline1 = toline1[0].GetChildren(); // ctrl[]\item[0]\item[0]
// and so on...
```